# Sprockets error and undefined method `remove_colmun' in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I'm trying to remove some attribute from my table using rails migration, I create the migration file and write this code :

```
class RemoveCompanySendReportAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_colmun :companies, :time_limit_for_sending_report, :integer
    remove_column :companies, :automatically_send_report, :boolean
  end
end
```

it doesn't work and this is the error in my terminal :

> Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then use
>   `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
>   https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
>   (called from block in  at
>   /home/sa7noun/altagem-project/web/config/initializers/haml.rb:24)
>   == 20180412151847 RemoveCompanySendReportAttributes: migrating ================
>   -- remove_colmun(:companies, :time_limit_for_sending_report, :integer) rake aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later
>   migrations canceled:
>
> undefined method `remove_colmun' for

Comment: `undefined method remove_colmun` - you have a typo in first line of `change` method

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1**

> Please register a mime type using register_mime_type then use  register_compressor or register_transformer.

It is a `sprockets` issue, the quick fix is

```
gem 'sprockets', '3.6.3'
```

but existing one will work on the production env.

**Part 2**

And migration error for `remove_column` you have written `remove_colmun` it is the wrong type that's why

> undefined method `remove_colmun' for

it will be `remove_column`

And look while you remove a column you don't need to mention the field type like `integer` or `boolean` or etc... Just simply

```
remove_column :companies, :time_limit_for_sending_report
```

Once you make any update in your Gemfile, ensure you run `bundle install` or `update`

Comment: If you're using `remove_column` in the migration's change method, adding the type will make the migration reversible if you need that.

Comment: I launched the command again without modify anything  and this time it works ! and I do not know why!

Comment: I think you rename the `remove_colmun` to  `remove_column` because the right is `remove_column`